# How to use a dataset to fill in a missing column in another set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, analytics

**Naive problem here:** let's say I have a dataframe, that is divided into `df1` and `df2`.
Now, `df1` is composed of the following variables:

| categ_var_1 | categ_var_2 | binary_target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 4 | 0 |
| B | 5 | 0 |
| B | 5 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Goal:** I want to use `df1` to fill in the missing column in `df2`, which has the same categorical variables (with different data), but *the binary_target is completely missing*:

| categ_var_1 | categ_var_2 |
| --- | --- |
| F | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 1 |
| ... | ... |

Which would be the best approach to resolve this in a simple manner?
My first guess was to use a Machine Learning model (using categorical variables as predictors), but I wouldn't be able to contrast the results, since `df2` has no target variable.
My second guess was to merge both sets and do a column-imputation, though the final result wouldn't be accurate.
What do you think? Any help would be highly apppreciated! (The only restriction is to use Python!)

Comment: can you display a simple of df2?

Comment: df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'city':['Lehi', 'Boston', 'Denver', 'San Francisco', 'Atlanta'], 
    'population_thousands':[50-100, 1-50, 100-300, 1-50]})

Answer (score 2):

If you have all possible pairs of "categ_var_1" and "categ_var_2", you can map category values to target values and use the mapper on `df2`:

Something like:

```
mapper = df1.set_index(['categ_var_1','categ_var_2'])['binary_target'].to_dict()
out = df2.apply(tuple, axis=1).map(mapper)
```

Then it gives:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    1.0
```

As you can see there are lots of NaN values that because those combinations are not in `mapper`.

Then what you can do is to create dummy variables from each category and use classification algorithm, maybe like logistic regression (scikit-learn has a class for it). Use `df1` as a training set and `df2` as a target set. This will obviously give you a prediction, not an exact value. Also note that depending on the number of options in each category, the size of the independent variables might become enormous, so the size of `df1` must be big as well, otherwise the prediction won't make much sense.